# Need to pass a generic filter function to list of objects to create where clause

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list of Countries in a dbContext using EfCore

I want to implement a generic way of filtering this list

```
    bool FilterCountriesv1(Country s)
    {
        var result = s.Name.StartsWith("A") && s.Name.Length > 4;
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<List<Country>> GetCountriesAsync(Func<Country, bool> func)
    {
        var allCountries = DbContext.Countries.AsQueryable();
        var filteredCountries = allCountries.Where(x=>func(x)).AsQueryable();
        var result = await filteredCountries.ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

Where I use it like this

```
var countries = await GetCountriesAsync(FilterCountriesv1);
```

When I run this I get the error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Country>.Where(c => Invoke(__func_0, c[Country])
)' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, 
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), 
AsAsyncEnumerable()
```

Not sure how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can use pure delegates when trying to execute against sql. EF cant translate you pure delegate to sql.

Try

```
Expression<Func<Country, bool>> expected = p=> p.Name.StartsWith("A") && p.Name.Length > 4;
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the type and have it generic?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @COLD TOLD you should use an expression

Change your code to retrieve data to this:

```
private async Task<List<Country>> GetCountriesAsync(Expression<Func<Country, bool>> expression)
{
    var allCountries = DbContext.Countries.AsQueryable();
    var filteredCountries = allCountries.Where(expression).AsQueryable();
    var result = await filteredCountries.ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Change your filter to return an expression

```
Expression<Func<Country, bool>> FilterCountriesv1(Country s)
{
    return (x) => x.Name.StartsWith("A") && x.Name > 4;

    // if you want to use s as a filter you can do
    // return (x) => x.Name.StartsWith(s.Name) && x.Name > 4
}
```

And call like this:

```
var countries = await GetCountriesAsync(FilterCountriesv1(new Country() { Name = "A"} ));
```

**For conversion use this (install nuget package Serialize.Linq)**

```
private string SerializeExpression(Expression expression)
{
    string result;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            new ExpressionSerializer(new JsonSerializer()).Serialize(stream, expression);
                
            stream.Position = 0;
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }


    return result;
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> DeserializeExpression<T>(string expression)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> result;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(expression);
            writer.Flush();

            stream.Position = 0;

            result = new ExpressionSerializer(new JsonSerializer()).Deserialize(stream) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
        }

    return result;
}
```

And then you can do something like this

```
string expression = SerializeExpression(FilterCountriesv1(new Country() { Name = "A"}));
var countries = dbContext.Countries.Where(DeserializeExpression<Country>(expression)).ToList();
```

*Note that the JsonSerializer used for serializing and deserializing is the one under Serializers.Linq.Serializers and not the one under Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: How can I cconvert the expressoon to a string?  I would like to take this expression and serialize it to a string and then be able to reload it

Comment: Updated answer to serialize and deserialize

Answer (score -1):

The filter should be a string and convert it to the lambda expression, but make sure the property exists in the passed in model. Try like below:

```
public List<T> GetFilterResult<T>(IQueryable<T> currentlist, string filter)
{
    var exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<T, bool>(ParsingConfig.Default, false, filter, currentlist);
    var func = exp.Compile();
    var result = currentlist.Where(func).AsQueryable().ToList();
    return result;
}

string Filter()
{
    string filter = "x => x.Name.StartsWith(\"A\") && x.Name.Length > 4";
    return filter;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var countries = _context.Countries.AsQueryable();
var result = GetFilterResult(countries, Filter());
```

Comment: I like the look of this but I don’t get why it’s been down voted?

Comment: Although I do need to be able to add this filter before I call to list as I am using IQueryable

Comment: @Paul, you can use `AsQueryable()` and pass this `IQueryable` object to the filter method. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will try that! Wish there was a way for people to give down vote reasons

Comment: This will cost you a lot at runtime _and_ when maintaining the code. Do not do this unless you really, really, really have no other choice.

Comment: Ok what is the cost at runtime? Does it take a while to compile the  expression?